# Can you define Jekyll config defaults from variables in another file?

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to do this because I'm using a CMS where users will be able to edit a data file to make changes to the page instead of the _config.yml.
I'm wondering if it's possible to reference a variable from the data file and place this reference within the _config.yml.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do;

**Data File (/_data/site-data.yml)**

```
navigation:
  navigation_colour: '#462634'
```

**Config File (/_config.yml)**

```
defaults:
  -
    values:
      navigation:
        navigation_colour: site.data.site-data.navigation.navigation-colour
```

Is something similar to this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Even if I could 'include' the data file underneath the defaults that would work

Comment: Data file content can't be accesed from `_config.yml` **but** in this case, you don't need them. Wouldn't be the same to define new attributes like *navigation* in data files and then read them in a layout file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll does not parse variables in `_config.yml`. However inside your blog you can use liquid tags like `{{site-data.navigation.navigation-colour}}`. See [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/).

If its mandate to replace variables in `_config.yml` then use a custom or standard replacement plugin with grunt. So effective grunt build task will first perform **token replacement** in `_config.yml` and then do **jekyll build**.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign at least in one config-file variables, I have not tested this over multiple files.

[Variables inside YAML](https://idratherbewriting.com/documentation-theme-jekyll/mydoc_yaml_tutorial.html#example-6-variables)

YAML, `hello` will become `Greetings earthling!`

```
something: &hello Greetings earthling!
myref: *hello
```

MARKDOWN

```
{{ site.data.samplelist.myref }}
```

Comment: Sidenote - gotta make sure to restart Jekyll after setting `_config.yml` variables. I just spent a few minutes wondering why variables weren't showing